# Unable to take input from a file containing string variables

Tags: c++, string

I decided to make a phonebook in c++ and decided to take input of names, address and number from a file.
So I made a class called contact and declared the  public variables name, address and number.
Using a constructor I initialized these to name="noname"(string), number=0(int), address="no address"(string)
Now my body of main goes as:

```
int main(){

contact *d;

d= new contact[200];

string name,add;

int choice,modchoice;//Variable for switch statement

int phno,phno1;

int i=0;
int initsize=0, i1=0;//i is declared as a static int variable

bool flag=false,flag_no_blank=false;


//TAKE DATA FROM FILES.....
//We create 3 files names, phone numbers, Address and then abstract the data from these files first!

fstream f1;
fstream f2;
fstream f3;

string file_input_name; 
string file_input_address;

int file_input_number;


f1.open("./names");

while(f1>>file_input_name){

  d[i].name=file_input_name;

  i++;

}
initsize=i;


f2.open("./numbers");

while(f2>>file_input_name){

  d[i1].phonenumber=file_input_number;
  i1++;

}


f3.open("./address");

while(f3>>file_input_address){

  d[i1].address=file_input_address;

  i1++;

}
```

now when I later search for a particular entry by name, the name is displayed correctly but the phoneumber is returned as a garbage value and address as "Noaddress"
I dont understand why this is happening...
In case u want to look at entire code, do let me know....

This is how i search for a particular entry which returns the name if matched but returns garbage for phone number....

```
cout<<"\nEnter the name";//Here it is assumed that no two contacts can have same contact number or address but may have the same name.
cin>>name;

int k=0,val;
cout<<"\n\nSearching.........\n\n";

for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
  if(d[j].name==name){
    k++;            
    cout<<k
        <<".\t"
        <<d[j].name
        <<"\t"<<d[j].phonenumber
        <<"\t"<<d[j].address
        <<"\n\n";
    val=j;                  
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I figured out the problem....
the problem is that i1 should be set to 0 after the second loop
and that the file taking input numbers should be f2.open("numbers") and not names....silly mistake!!

Comment: `i1`? `f2`? Have you ever considered *meaningful* identifiers?

Answer (score 2):

When your reading the file with the phone numbers

```
f2.open("./numbers");

while(f2>>file_input_name){

d[i1].phonenumber=file_input_number;
i1++;

}
```

You store the phone number in the string `file_input_name` but then you use a different var, `file_input_number` to store the information in the array d;

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++, and not C, you should take advantage of the things that come with the language. Don't use arrays to store your data, use a `std::vector`. That way you don't have to remember how many things you have already put into the vector, because you can always ask the vector to tell you the `size()`.

If I had to read in the three files I would go like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::fstream;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

class contact {
public:
  string name;
  string address;
  int phone;
};

void print_contact(const contact &c) {
  cout << "name " << c.name << " address " << c.address << " phone " << c.phone << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  vector<contact> contacts;

  string name;
  string address;
  int phone;

  fstream f1("d:\\names.txt");
  fstream f2("d:\\phones.txt");
  fstream f3("d:\\addresses.txt");

  // note that I am using getline() here.
  while (getline(f1, name) && f2 >> phone && getline(f3, address)) {
    contact c;
    c.name = name;
    c.address = address;
    c.phone = phone;
    contacts.push_back(c);
  }

  for_each(contacts.begin(), contacts.end(), print_contact);

  // for the Windows console window
  cout << "Press return to continue ...";
  string s;
  getline(cin, s);
  return 0;
}
```